# Geometric Realization of a Simplicial Category

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $S:\varDelta^{op}\to (cat)$ be a functor where the category on the right is the category whose objects are categories with cofibrations and morphisms are exact functors(from Waldhausen's paper, Algebraic K-Theory of spaces). Waldhausen talks of the geometric realization of such a simplicial category. In the case of a simplicial set, I know how to construct the geometric realization. However, in this case, $S_n$ is a category. It is not clear to me if he is assuming that this is a small category for each n, in which case we could proceed to construct the geometric realization as in the case of a simplicial set. If each $S_n$ is not a small category, then is it still possible to define the geometric realization of $S$?

Comment: Is this a question about how to interpret something that you are reading? (If so, what?) Or a question about how to make a useful new definition for some purpose of your own? (If so, what purpose?)

Comment: Waldhausen first takes the nerve in order to obtain a bisimplicial set and then takes the geometric realization of that. He doesn't say so very explicitly, but it is clear from his arguments. Compare also with Thomason-Trobaugh, section 1.5.

Comment: Yes, the revision was very good in that it was total!  The question now makes sense, and I have changed my downvote to an upvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Buehler states in the comments, Waldhausen is taking the nerve degreewise, and then taking the diagonal of the resulting bisimplicial set. This is a model for the homotopy colimit of the simplicial diagram of nerves.

Waldhausen mentions the question of smallness himself in a remark on p. 14 of *Algebraic K-theory of spaces*. As he observes, it is only necessary to assume that his categories with cofibrations and weak equivalences are small up to weak equivalence.